# make nginx not log "no user/password was provided for basic authentication" in error logs

Tags: nginx, logging, authentication

I've added password protection to a lot of my domain via nginx by adding:

```
    auth_basic            "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file  /usr/ssl/htpasswd;
```

to the nginx vhosts.

I log all errors to log files in an effort to eradicate all errors but I get a ton of "no user/password was provided for basic authentication" errors in my log files as a result of the password protection.

I would like to tell nginx not to log those errors.. is there a directive to do that? I've looked but haven't found it yet...

If you know then please tell me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is loggeg on the most basic error level. check the source code:
http://lxr.nginx.org/source/src/http/modules/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.c

Line 141

It cannot be disabled.